# How can I make azure subnet installation re-entrant with terraform?

Tags: azure, terraform

In my Azure infrastructure, I have a policy that prevents me from creating subnets without a network security group. Because I want to create a flexible postgres server, I need to create a delegated subnet. In order to create a delegated subnet, I need to separate subnet from vnet creation, i.e. I need to create the subnet in a separate resource than the vnet. Theoretically, I should do this:

```
resource "azurerm_virtual_network" "vnet_hub" {
  name                = "HubVnet"
  location            = var.location
  resource_group_name = var.resource_group_name
  address_space       = ["10.0.0.0/21"]
}

resource "azurerm_subnet" "db" {
  name                 = "db-subnet"
  resource_group_name  = var.resource_group_name
  virtual_network_name = azurerm_virtual_network.vnet_hub.name
  address_prefixes     = ["10.0.3.0/24"]

  delegation {
    name = "delegation"

    service_delegation {
      name    = "Microsoft.DBforPostgreSQL/flexibleServers"
      actions = ["Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/subnets/join/action"]
    }
  }
}

resource "azurerm_network_security_group" "db" {
  name                = "db-nsg"
  location            = var.location
  resource_group_name = var.resource_group_name

  security_rule {
    name                       = "test123"
    priority                   = 100
    direction                  = "Inbound"
    access                     = "Allow"
    protocol                   = "Tcp"
    source_port_range          = "*"
    destination_port_range     = "*"
    source_address_prefix      = "*"
    destination_address_prefix = "*"
  }
}

resource "azurerm_subnet_network_security_group_association" "db" {
  subnet_id                 = azurerm_subnet.db.id
  network_security_group_id = azurerm_network_security_group.db.id
}
```

However, that is not possible to do, because the delegated subnet is first created without network security group, and only then it is associated with an NSG. Azure complains that no subnet can be created without an NSG because of the azure policy we have put in place. We don't want to get rid of that policy.

So the only solution I have been able to come up with until now is the following:

```
resource "azurerm_virtual_network" "vnet_hub" {
  name                = "HubVnet"
  location            = var.location
  resource_group_name = var.resource_group_name
  address_space       = ["10.0.0.0/21"]
}

resource "azurerm_network_security_group" "db" {
  name                = "db-nsg"
  location            = var.location
  resource_group_name = var.resource_group_name

  security_rule {
    name                       = "test123"
    priority                   = 100
    direction                  = "Inbound"
    access                     = "Allow"
    protocol                   = "Tcp"
    source_port_range          = "*"
    destination_port_range     = "*"
    source_address_prefix      = "*"
    destination_address_prefix = "*"
  }
}

resource "null_resource" "database_subnet" {
  depends_on = [azurerm_virtual_network.vnet_hub]

  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command     = format("%s/%s", path.module, "add_database_subnet.sh")
    interpreter = ["sh"]
    environment = {
      RESOURCE_GROUP_NAME       = var.resource_group_name
      SUBNET_NAME               = "db-subnet"
      VNET_NAME                 = azurerm_virtual_network.vnet_hub.name
      ADDRESS_PREFIX            = "10.0.3.0/24"
      NETWORK_SECURITY_GROUP_ID = azurerm_network_security_group.db.id
    }
  }
}
```

where the `add_database_subnet.sh` contains

```bash
#! /bin/sh

az network vnet subnet create \
  --name "${SUBNET_NAME}" \
  --vnet-name "${VNET_NAME}" \
  --resource-group "${RESOURCE_GROUP_NAME}" \
  --address-prefixes "${ADDRESS_PREFIX}" \
  --network-security-group "${NETWORK_SECURITY_GROUP_ID}" \
  --service-endpoints "Microsoft.Storage" \
  --delegations "Microsoft.DBforPostgreSQL/flexibleServers"
```

While that works when I run `terraform deploy` once, it doesn't when I run it twice. The `db-subnet` gets deleted when I run `terraform deploy` a second time, leaving me with no more subnet for my database.

I want to be able to run multiple `terraform deploy` for the sake of updating my infrastructure, for example. How should I proceed? what can I do to make it happen? Is there a way without a shell script?

Comment: What's wrong with the first TF code of yours? What errors do you get?

Comment: Something like "Unable to deploy Subnet without NSG"

Comment: which version is the provider you use?

Comment: I am using provider version 3.47.0

Comment: It seems that what you encountered here is a known limitation of the `hashicorp/azurerm` provider, discussed in closed [issue #18173](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-azurerm/issues/18173). [Issue #9022](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-azurerm/issues/9022) seems to represent documenting a different policy approach which prohibits creating a network interface in a subnet without an NSG, rather than blocking creating the subnet itself. Maybe that alternative policy would meet the same goals as your current one, but give more flexibility for Terraform workflow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, in the end, it turns out I made a mistake that is not shown in my initial post. I created multiple subnets inside of my `vnet_hub` VNet, some of which were in-lined in the `vnet_hub` resource, while some others were created with the `azurerm_subnet` resource. As documented by terraform, this is not supported, hence my issue.

However, contrary to what is suggested in [this answer to my post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75765539/4434140), using the

```
lifecycle  {
  prevent_destroy = true
}
```

brings me nothing. Without that `lifecycle` block, and all my subnets created with the `azurerm_subnet` resource, I never get my subnets destroyed. I can therefore happily update my infrastructure without having to integrate that block in my configuration.

Answer (score 1):

**I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and below is the result**

First, I created **Virtual Network** and the **Network Security Group** resources, Then I create the delegated **Subnet** resource and associate it with the **VNet** and **NSG** resources using Terraform.

You can use **Terraform** `lifecycle` meta-argument to prevent the deletion of the subnet resource. You can set the `prevent_destroy` attribute to `true` in the `azurerm_subnet` resource block to prevent it from being deleted.

```
 lifecycle  {
        prevent_destroy = true
        }
```

`prevent_destroy` to true, terraform will not remove the subnet resource even if it believes that it is no longer required. This should solve the issue you are encountering when running **Terraform** multiple times.

**Terraform code:**

```
    provider  "azurerm"  {
    features  {}
    }
    
    #Resource Group Creation
    
    resource  "azurerm_resource_group"  "sqlrg"  {
    name = "test-resources"
    location = "eastus"
    }
    
    #Virtual Network creation
    
    resource  "azurerm_virtual_network"  "sqlvnet"  {
    name = "example-security-group"
    address_space = ["10.0.0.0/16"]
    location = azurerm_resource_group.sqlrg.location
    resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.sqlrg.name
    }
         #NSG Creation
         
    resource  "azurerm_network_security_group"  "sqlnsg"  {
    name = "example-security-group"
    location = azurerm_resource_group.sqlrg.location
    resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.sqlrg.name
    
    # Subnet Creation
    
    resource  "azurerm_subnet"  "sqlsubnet"  {
    name = "example-security-group"
    resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.sqlrg.name
    virtual_network_name = azurerm_virtual_network.sqlvnet.name
    address_prefixes = ["10.0.5.0/24"]
    delegation  {
    name = "delegation"
    service_delegation  {
    name = "Microsoft.DBforPostgreSQL/flexibleServers"
    actions = ["Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/subnets/join/action"]
    }
    }
    lifecycle  {
    prevent_destroy = true
    }
    }
 } 
 resource  "azurerm_subnet_network_security_group_association"  "sqlnic"  {
    subnet_id = azurerm_subnet.sqlsubnet.id
    network_security_group_id = azurerm_network_security_group.sqlnsg.id
    }
```

**Terrform Apply:**

[image]

When I try to add & update the subnet, it does not delete the existing subnet.

**Updating Subnet IP Prefix**

[image]

**Adding another subnet in the same Vnet**

[image]

When I check the same in the portal, it got updated without destroying existing resources as below.

[image]

Comment: do you have enabled the azure policy "Subnets should have a Network Security Group"? because on my infrastructure, if I don't have that policy, it works too. My issue is related to creating the subnet with the azure policy enabled.

Comment: As you mentioned Subnet is deleting, when I run the terraform apply again for infrastructure update,use 'prevent_destroy = true'.

Comment: Yeah, I understand that, and thanks for the hint, I'll try it out. Nevertheless, with the azure policy for the NSGs on subnets in place, I am not allowed to create the subnet the same way you do. I am not allowed to make it happen with the terraform resource azurerm_subnet. I can only create it with a shell script, as far as I know.

Comment: So, I gave it a try and it doesn't work. Some subnets still get deleted, some others don't. This thing is a nightmare.